# Can I create a kubernetes role in 'exclude mode'?

Tags: kubernetes

For example, I want to create a role without "get", "list" or "watch" resource "pod" permissions. Is there any convenient way to quickly create this rule?

```
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  #
  # at the HTTP level, the name of the resource for accessing Pod
  # objects is "pods"
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, roles are purely additive, [there are no deny rules](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole).

In the ticket [Add Support to Deny RBAC Rules #85963](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/85963) there is lots of discussions around this. The issue was eventually [closed with the follwoing rationale](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/85963#issuecomment-708403412)

> This is unlikely to make progress as an issue. While there is clear
> interest, deny rules were considered and decided against during
> development of RBAC because of the complexity, implications to
> upgrades, and unclear superuser/non-superuser interactions.